# Folded banner using css and border and fade

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out howto do a folded banner with a red border using css.

Is it possible to do a smiliar one to the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Yup, it is. No problem at all.

Comment: I know that you already have an answer, but what all have you tried and what were the results?  it may help someone to know what code was tried and what the results were,  they could be looking for something similar, and you may give them the answer they are looking for just by showing what didn't work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done with psuedo-elements.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/bKKLn/2/)

```
div::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -12px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #AA0000;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hey there is a nice tutorial on Tutsplus that might be a good starter.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-practical-css-shapes/

Demo here:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/nettuts/676_cssShapes/shapes.html

Answer (score 2):

I would request that you actually TRY to do what you are asking, instead of having other users do coding for you. That being said, I think the trickiest part of this would be implementing the triangle portion on the bottom. To do this in CSS, see this link:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: I can not understand why this was downvoted. Actually, i was thinking the same exact thing.