# Show div when post has class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Update**
I'd modded the CSS given by David Thomas a bit. Its now a banner.

```
.div.popular::before {
  /* setting the default styles for
     the generated content: */
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #F60;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I would like to make a folded corner sort of like in this post: [Folded banner using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720871/folded-banner-using-css-and-border-and-fade)

--- Original post ---

Let me first explain what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to give some post some extra attention by making a little circle with some call-to-action text in it.

But I only want this to trigger when a div has a specific class.

So if the div the class `populair` or `sale` I would like to have a little circle show up on that post. This script what I am using right now.

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
  if($("#front-page-items").hasClass('populair')){
    $(".populair-div").show();
  }
  if($("#front-page-items").hasClass('sale')){
    $(".sale-div").show();
  }    
});
```

And this HTML:

```
<div class="populair-div" style="display:none;">
    <strong>Populair</strong>
</div>
<div class="sale-div" style="display:none;">
    <strong>Sale</strong>
</div>
```

But this only show's the `populair-div` and not the other one. I'm guessing my script is wrong. Should I use `else` for all the other call-to-action classes?

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
  if($("#front-page-items").hasClass('populair')){
    $(".populair-div").show();
  }
  else($("#front-page-items").hasClass('sale')){
    $(".sale-div").show();
  } 
  else($("#front-page-items").hasClass('Free')){
    $(".free-div").show();
  } // and so on
});
```

Is there someone that could help me out? Also is it possible to `echo` the div so I don't have to write a whole div for every call-to-action div?

Comment: thers is a typo in second condition, It need to `else if`. There cannot be multiple else

Comment: Where - in the HTML you posted - is the "*circle*" you wish to add? If it's nested within the `<strong>` element, or is a subsequent sibling of that element, then you could achieve this with CSS quite simply. As for the latter part of your question what content did you want this `<div>` to have, we're here to answer *specific*, not theoretical, problems. And yes: both JavaScript and PHP could generate the element(s) for you, so long as there's some kind of regular structure to it.

Comment: In short I just want a circle with the text sale to show up when the class `sale` is added to the div. And if the class `populair` is added to the div I want a circle with the text popular. Can that be done with CSS alone, because that would be great! @DavidThomas

Comment: So the element with the class-name of "populair-div" should have a circle within it with the text of "popular", and the element with the class-name of "sale-div" should have a circle with the text of "sale"? And *both* of those elements should be made visible?

Comment: Yup, that's basically it... But if there is no class then nothing should be displayed... @DavidThomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this, where the displayed text is explicitly linked to the class-name of the element it's easiest to use CSS and the generated content available, effectively hiding the elements you don't wish to show by default and then explicitly allowing elements you want to show, along with the generated content of those elements (using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements:

```css
div {
  /* preventing <div> elements
     from showing by default: */
  display: none;
}
div.populair-div,
div.sale-div {
  /* ensuring that elements matching
     the selectors above (<div>
     elements with either the 'sale-div'
     or 'populair-div' class-names
     are shown: */
  display: block;
}
div.populair-div::before,
div.sale-div::before {
  /* setting the default styles for
     the generated content: */
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div.populair-div::before {
  /* setting the text with the
     "content" property: */
  content: "Popular";
  /* providing a specific colour
     for the generated contents'
     border: */
  border-color: #0c0;
}
div.sale-div::before {
  content: "Sale";
  border-color: #f90;
}
/* entirely irrelevant, just so you can
   see a (slightly prettified) difference
   should you remove the default display
   property for the <div> elements: */

code {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
em {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="neither-popular-nor-sale">
  <p>
    This element should not be shown, it has neither a class of <code>"populair-div"</code>  <em>or</em>  <code>"sale-div"</code>.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="populair-div">
</div>
<div>Also not to be shown.</div>
<div class="sale-div">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm glad to have been of help!

Comment: Just one more thing. If I may be so bold... I would like to have the following. I modded you CSS to make a banner. But could you perhaps show me how to do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720871/folded-banner-using-css-and-border-and-fade? Ill update my modded CSS in my OP. @DavidThomas

Comment: That would be a wholly new question, I think.

Comment: Yeah, thought so too. Any thanks again! I'll fiddle around with it a bit!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function for this. It will be shorter and clearer.

> Display or hide the matched elements.

Note: The buttons is for tests.

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
  init();     
});

function init() {
  $(".populair-div").toggle($("#front-page-items").hasClass('populair'));
  $(".sale-div").toggle($("#front-page-items").hasClass('sale'));  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="front-page-items" class="populair sale"></div>
<div class="populair-div">populair-div</div>
<div class="sale-div">sale-div</div>
<hr />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('front-page-items').classList.toggle('populair');init()">toggle populair</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('front-page-items').classList.toggle('sale');init()">toggle sale</button>
```